# ajax in internet explorer 8.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

i have written code according to which on basis of first dropdown second dropdown is populated the code is working in mozilla but it is not working in internet explorer 8.0

```
function stateListOnChange(str1) {

var xmlhttp;
if (str1 == "") {
    document.getElementById("CityList").innerHTML = "";
    return;
}
if (str1 == "") {
    document.getElementById("CityList").disabled = true;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("CityList").disabled = false;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("CityList").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "../includes/xml_cities.asp?q1=" + str1, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

but the code is not working in ie 8.0 please give me the solution

Comment: Please take some time to format your code properly. That will greatly improve the probability you get an answer.

Comment: really? in late 2011 and you still use plain old javascript? ASP.NET use jQuery now, and there are so many examples (even from Microsoft) on how to do what you want.

Comment: How are you serving your document? If it is an `XML` document i.e. `XHTML` as opposed to `HTML` then IE doesn't allow `innerHTML` to be set directly. You need to change the DOM by adding/removing nodes.

Comment: I would love to know if your code ever get's into the line `document.getElementById("CityList").disabled = true;` ...

Comment: @balexandre: jQuery provides easy functionality for the developer, but often at a cost to the end user. As with everything, there are pros and cons that must be weighed. Perhaps you should not harangue someone who has weighed the benefits and chosen the situationally-appropriate option.

Comment: "Not working" is not a helpful description of the problem. Do some tracing to figure out what actually happens. Is the request made? Is the call back executed? What data is received? What errors are reported?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins with that code... I would bet it was taken by a tutorial and he does not know better... that's why.

Comment: actualy it is not making request in ie

Comment: neither jquery is working nor request is sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you replace this:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

with this:

```
try  
{  
    // Internet Explorer 
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e)  
{  
    try   
    { 
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari  
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }  
    catch (e)    
    {   
        try     
        {      
            xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        }    
        catch (e)      
        {      
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");      
            return false;      
        }    
    }  
}
```

This code will provide more options for initializing the request, and will provide feedback when an unsupported browser is used.

Answer (score -1):

add the jQuery script into your code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then use

```
function stateListOnChange(state) {
    if (state == "") {
        $("#CityList").html("").prop("disabled", true);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $("#CityList").prop("disabled", false);
    }

    $.get("../includes/xml_cities.asp", { "q1" : state }, function(data) {
        $("#CityList").html(data);
    }); 
}
```

and you hook up the event, either

```
<input id="CityList" ... onchange="stateListOnChange(this.value);" />
```

or simply using jQuery as well

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#CityList").bind("change", function() {
         stateListOnChange( $(this).val() );
     });
});
```

and it works in **any browser** ... *even a mobile one*!